# Dynamically creating a dictionary in python

Tags: python, django

I want to dynamically build a dictionary based on the string.

I have 5 strings:

```
ABC
ABC BCD DEF
ABC BCD FGH
ABC BCD FGH IJK
ABC DEF GHI
```

I want to create this into a dict:

```
dict = {
 "ABC" : {
   "BCD": {"DEF": {}, "FGH":{IJK}},
   "DEF": {"GHI"},
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried so far, but I'm not sure how to create the new key if there is a key error.

```
# orgs = list of string from about
for org in orgs:
    org_path_sp = org .strip().split()   
    org_cur = org_dict
    for org_el in org_path_sp:
        try:
            org_cur = org_cur[org_el.strip()]

        except KeyError:
            pass
            # create the new entry
```

Comment: So the inner one is a `set`? Or should it be a dictionary that maps to nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. What you should do is each time **construct an empty dictionary** in case the **key is missing**:

```
org_dict = {}

for org in orgs.split('\n'):
    org_path_sp = org .strip().split()   
    org_cur = org_dict
    for org_el in org_path_sp:
        org_el = org_el.strip()
        if org_el not in org_cur:
            org_cur[org_el] = org_cur = {}
        else:
            org_cur = org_cur[org_el]
```

Or we can alter your code a bit:

```
org_dict = {}

for org in orgs.split('\n'):
    org_path_sp = org .strip().split()   
    org_cur = org_dict
    for org_el in org_path_sp:
        org_el = org_el.strip()
        try:
            org_cur = org_cur[org_el]
        except KeyError:
            org_cur[org_el] = org_cur = {}
```

For example:

```
>>> orgs = '''ABC
... ABC BCD DEF
... ABC BCD FGH
... ABC BCD FGH IJK
... ABC DEF GHI'''
>>> org_dict = {}
>>> 
>>> for org in orgs.split('\n'):
...     org_path_sp = org .strip().split()   
...     org_cur = org_dict
...     for org_el in org_path_sp:
...         org_el = org_el.strip()
...         if org_el not in org_cur:
...             org_cur[org_el] = org_cur = {}
...         else:
...             org_cur = org_cur[org_el]
... 
>>> org_dict
{'ABC': {'BCD': {'DEF': {}, 'FGH': {'IJK': {}}}, 'DEF': {'GHI': {}}}}
```

Here the inner elements are not *`set`s*, but `dict`s. It would make more sense to use dictionaries here, since if you later want to update your elements and add extra `orgs`, then we can easily run thins program again over a partially filled dictionary.

Note that dictionaries are *unoredered*. There is thus no guarantee about the order of the keys in the result. You can use an [**`OrderedDict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if that is necessary. For example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

org_dict = OrderedDict()

for org in orgs.split('\n'):
    org_path_sp = org .strip().split()   
    org_cur = org_dict
    for org_el in org_path_sp:
        org_el = org_el.strip()
        if org_el not in org_cur:
            org_cur[org_el] = org_cur = OrderedDict()
        else:
            org_cur = org_cur[org_el]
```

This would then result in:

```
>>> pprint(org_dict)
OrderedDict([('ABC',
              OrderedDict([('BCD',
                            OrderedDict([('DEF', OrderedDict()),
                                         ('FGH',
                                          OrderedDict([('IJK',
                                                        OrderedDict())]))])),
                           ('DEF', OrderedDict([('GHI', OrderedDict())]))]))])
```

We *can* convert these back into dictionaries, but then the order will again be lost.